# How to replicate code for Facebook image gestures?

Tags: image, uiscrollview, zooming, gesture

I am developing an educational app that is made of multiple images. I am also new at coding and XCode. I wanted to know how to get my images so they respond to the gesture similar to the photos on facebook (swiping, min/max zooming, scrolling all on one image). I have the `UIImage` in `UIScrollview`.

Can I add all the gestures in `UIScrollView` or do I have to add each gesture separately? Because the app is made up of multiple png images do I have to connect each image separately or is there a method to implement one code for the entire program?

I am using Storyboard and have minimal coding.

If this information is already out there I would greatly appreciate some direction. I have tried to use "Basic Zooming Using the Pinch Gestures" from the iOS library with little success.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial.
http://www.raywenderlich.com/6567/uigesturerecognizer-tutorial-in-ios-5-pinches-pans-and-more

In this they go over exactly what your wanting, zooming in and out images and swiping. Pretty much you use UIGestureRecognizers. :)